# Display drawable exactly the size of the imageView to use as a placeholder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

Friends I have checked [get drawable exactly the size of the imageView to use as a placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277569/get-drawable-exactly-the-size-of-the-imageview-to-use-as-a-placeholder)

But it did not help me

My problem is I want to display a place holder exactly of the image size

The Image size is dynamic , I am getting the image height and width from server , using that I am calculating adjusted width and height

For Example in one row of list I have to display 400 * 300 size of image and in another row I have to display 700 * 500 size of image

Now I want the place holder should fill the area 400*300 in first case and 700*500 in second case , This thing I am not able to achieve ,

How can I achieve this ?

```
mDisplayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.test_user)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();



    mAdjustedWidth = mWindowWidth - 10;
            mAdjustedHeight = 400;
            try {
                int width = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_TWIDTH));
                if(width > 0) {
                    mAdjustedHeight = (mAdjustedWidth * cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_THEIGHT))) / width;
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            talkImageView.getLayoutParams().height = mAdjustedHeight;
            talkImageView.getLayoutParams().width = mAdjustedWidth;
            talkImageView.requestLayout();

 mImageLoader.displayImage(talkImageThumbnil,talkImageView,mTalksDisplayImageOptions,new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    // ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)progressBar.getTag();
                    //progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    talkImageView.getLayoutParams().height = mAdjustedHeight;
                    talkImageView.getLayoutParams().width = mAdjustedWidth;
                    talkImageView.requestLayout();
                    talkImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_place_holder);
                    Log.d(TAG, " Progress bar  visisble ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    //ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)progressBar.getTag();
                    //progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    //ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)progressBar.getTag();
                    //progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    //ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)progressBar.getTag();
                    //progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            });
```

XML Image View

I am struggling for this from days , please help me

Place holder look like this before image download

[image]

Once Image dowloaded it look like below image

[image]

I want that the place holder should fill the exact height and width of the image which is about to display

Comment: "My problem is I want to display a place holder exactly of the image size" what image size? what is your problem actually?

Comment: @psink The image size is dynamic  it could be any size server sends me the size and I calculate it and adjust the height accordingly

Comment: the height of what? post some images describing your issue maybe?

Comment: @psink I have edited question and added use case please have a look

Comment: tried android:adjustViewBounds ?

Comment: Yeah I tried , I am really stuck with this

Comment: Yeah I am using it , let me post XM Image view code

Comment: so post an image with what you are getting with android:adjustViewBounds

Comment: @psink I have added image

Comment: so make the `Drawable` that returns intrinsic width / heigh exactly as your image size

Comment: I did it as per my understanding ..can u please post an answer with code ...

Comment: you can also use `ShapeDrawable` which has methods for that, read carefully `ShapeDrawable`'s docs

Comment: Okay great I will read Shapedrawable ..so we can not achieve this using imageview

Comment: no no no, you should use ShapteDrawable in ImageView

Comment: Okay ..can u please help me with this I really learning ui in Android ..please

Comment: I mean with some code

Answer (score 0):

Set the scale type of your ImageView to fitCenter ?

Comment: I was suggesting to use fitCenter because it adjusts the image to the ImageView, enlarging it if necessary while keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: I did it but still behaviour is same

Comment: I have edited the code , I have tried that also but it is not working

Comment: What's the issue? Do you want to stretch the placeholder image? Use fitXY in that case.